# Disable certain multiplayer maps in CoD BO2

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

Is it somehow possible to temporarily disable specific multiplayer maps in Black Ops II ?
I would like to enable only a few smalls maps while I level up my shotguns.

I've tried to remove some of the map files, but the game will hang on that. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, you have no control of map rotation in public play, ie play where you can level up. This is because you are in a public lobby, so everyone would have to have the specific maps disabled.

If you want to choose maps, custom modes are the only way.

Comment: However if you can convince enough of your friends to join your lobby (non-party) you could probably get them to help sway the vote towards a preferred map easier.

Comment: This is true but I'm just wondering why non-party is significant?

Comment: Well, to guarantee you get the map you want you'll need more than half the votes in a lobby. Last time I played I didn't think you could have more than a full team side in a party (forgive me if I'm wrong, it's been a while since I played CoD)

Comment: That assumes that all the lobby vote and that you are voting for either the previous map or a random map.

Comment: Well, he wants to *guarantee* that he gets a map he wants (out of the choices offered at least), not just a high chance. Holding the majority vote is going to do that for him, regardless if the other people vote with him or not (or not at all)